# Duplicating and removing sections using Jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a form which i want to clone. The form looks like this.

```
<form method="post">
    <div id=duplicator>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Client's Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add" onclick="duplicate()">ADD +</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove">DEL -</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    //Duplicator div close
    <div class="pull-right">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xm submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I duplicated the Division using following code:

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "duplicat0r" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

But the divisions are cloning after the submit button. I want to insert the cloned div before the submit button.

and how to remove the cloned division on clicking delete button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clone()` to copy element and use `before()` to insert element before selector.

```js
$(".add").click(function(){
    var clone = $(".form-group:first").clone();
    clone.find("input").val("");
    $(".buttonBox").before(clone);
});

$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(".form-group:last").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=duplicator>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Client's Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 buttonBox">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add">ADD +</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove">DEL -</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last12 = $('.col-md-12').last();
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
        $('.col-md-6').last().clone().insertBefore(last12);  
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        if($('.col-md-6').length > 1) {
            $('.col-md-6').last().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/noz2s4nh/6/

Comment: I want to clone the section if add button is clicked.

Comment: @SujanShrestha I've updated my answer to only clone when the add button is clicked. If you keep cloning the division the number of inputs will increment by powers of two, am I getting your question right?

Comment: Yes sir. Sections are increasing by power of two.

Comment: @SujanShrestha ok sounds good, I've added a jsfiddle to my answer. Give it a try and let me know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: The divisions are duplicating by the multiplication of 2. what i want is, if add button is clicked. only one division is increased.

Comment: @SujanShrestha I've updated my answer to add only one. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

This demo will:

- Initially have a text input, add button, and submit button.
- Click add button to add a group of cloned form elements.
- This clone is appended to the form.
- Each clone has a delete button.
- Click the delete button to remove the clone.
- There will always be at least one form-group.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('set');
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var btn1 = form1.querySelector('button');

function duplicate() {
  i++;
  var clone1 = original.cloneNode(true);

  clone1.id = "clone" + i;
  form1.appendChild(clone1);

  btn1.id = "btn" + i;
}

function delDupe() {

  var clone1 = document.getElementById('clone' + i);

  if (!clone1) {
    return false;
  }

  form1.removeChild(clone1);

  i--;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
form {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
label {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">

    <fieldset id='set' class="set">

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">

        <label>Client's Name</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_name" />

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 pull-left">

        <button class="btn btn-danger remove" onclick="delDupe()">DEL -</button>

      </div>

    </fieldset>

  </form>


  <div class="col-md-12 pull-left">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add" onclick="duplicate()">ADD +</button>

  </div>

  <div class="pull-right">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xm submit" name="submit" value="Submit" form="form1" />

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank You. Can you tell me how to change the id dynamically of cloned divisions.like form-group1 , from-group2

Comment: Your'e welcome, you can use a global var that is initially 0. When there is an addition, you increment that `i++` then reference the new value of that var to apply it to the id of the new object as a string ` obj+'i'`. If deleting an object then decrement i-- . There's a working example of that procedure within the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").on('click','.add',function(){
    var addd = $(".col-md-6").first().clone();
    $(".col-md-12").before(addd);
});
$("form").on('click','.remove',function(e){
    var subb = $(".col-md-6").last().remove();

});
});
```